# How can I generate Oracle output based on Parent ID?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

My Oracle database looks like this:

```
DR_ID  |  DR_PATH    |  DR_FILE_OR_FOLDER  |  DR_PARENT_FOLDER_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  one.txt    |  File               |  0
  2    |  two        |  Folder             |  0
  3    |  three.txt  |  File               |  0
  4    |  four.txt   |  File               |  2
  5    |  five       |  Folder             |  2
  6    |  six        |  Folder             |  5
  7    |  seven.txt  |  File               |  6
```

This table represent a folder structure and `DR_ID` is the Primary Key with a sequence. `DR_PATH` is File or Folder Name, `DR_FILE_OR_FOLDER` is type (File or Folder) and `DR_PARENT_FOLDER_ID` represent parent ID (`DR_ID`).

I need to create a query to get the relative path of a file of folder based on the `DR_ID` passed.

Example:- If I pass `DR_ID` 7, I need to get the output as `two\five\six\seven.txt`

How can I create a query for this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (dr_id, dr_path, dr_parent_folder_id) as
  2  (select 1, 'one.txt'  , 0 from dual union all
  3   select 2, 'two'      , 0 from dual union all
  4   select 3, 'three.txt', 0 from dual union all
  5   select 4, 'four.txt' , 2 from dual union all
  6   select 5, 'five'     , 2 from dual union all
  7   select 6, 'six'      , 5 from dual union all
  8   select 7, 'seven.txt', 6 from dual
  9  )
 10  select listagg(dr_path, '\') within group (order by level desc) result
 11  from test
 12  connect by dr_id = prior dr_parent_folder_id
 13  start with dr_id = &par_dr_id;
Enter value for par_dr_id: 7

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
two\five\six\seven.txt

SQL> /
Enter value for par_dr_id: 5

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
two\five

SQL>
```

Comment: The records are dynamic in the database and cannot include them in the query. So expecting a common way of doing it.

Comment: What does that mean? What is "included in query"? It appears that you don't understand the CTE or WITH factoring clause, I'm afraid. If you posted test case yourself, I wouldn't have to do it myself in order to show what that SELECT statement does. What you need is from line 10 to line 13 in my example.

Comment: Yes I am new to Oracle. I only need the select statement to execute in my C# project. Can you please provide a select statement only?

Comment: Lines 10 - 13, as I've said. `&par_dr_id` represents a parameter. `&` is used in SQL*Plus, other tools use `:`, I don't know what is used in C#.